# Concatenate strings in SQL query C#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a database and return two columns concatenated as one string, is there an easy way of doing this?

```
public ActionResult GetContactList (int? id) 
{
    var contacts = (from ofg in db.Contacts
                    where ((ofg.ContactId == id) && (ofg.Deleted == false))
                    select new 
                        {
                            (ofg.FirstName + ofg.Surname as ofg.FullName),
                            ofg.ContactID
                        }).OrderBy(ofg => ofg.FirstName);

    return this.Direct(contacts.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Is your example working? If not what exception do you get? Why do this in the DB and not via code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new anonymous object in this case would probably look more like this:

```
select new { FullName = ofg.FirstName + ofg.Surname, ContactID = ofg.ContactID }
```

Note then that this won't work:

```
OrderBy(ofg => ofg.FirstName)
```

Because there's no `FirstName` field in the object.  (Only `FullName` and `ContactID`.)  If you need to order by that field, you'll need to select it:

```
select new { FirstName = ofg.FirstName, FullName = ofg.FirstName + ofg.Surname, ContactID = ofg.ContactID }
```

You may also find in this logic that your `FullName` field isn't adding spaces between the names.  If you want that, you'll need to include it in the logic.

As a side note, things like a `FullName` field are often a good case for an actual model instead of an anonymous object.  Consider something like this:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, Surname);
        }
    }
}
```

That would encapsulate the `FullName` logic on the object where it belongs, and you can just select an instance of that object:

```
select new SomeModel { FirstName = ofg.FirstName, Surname = ofg.Surname, ContactID = ofg.ContactID }
```

This way consuming code wouldn't have to duplicate the logic of creating the model, the model itself contains the logic that it owns.  You can then continue to add more functionality from there, centralized to a single model.

Comment: `the model itself contains the logic that it owns` +1: Then you can also adapt that logic easily by e.g. changeing the `String.Format` string to print "LastName FirstName" instead of "FirstName LastName" if you need to...

Comment: Thanks, I've tried adding the full name method to the model as suggested above and get the error -The specified type member 'FullName' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Comment: @stephenjgray: Exactly what did you try?

Comment: David, I'll edit the question above with what I tried

Comment: @stephenjgray: You tried to edit this answer, not the question. Regarding your edit, this was incorrect: `select new { ofg.FullName, ofg.ContactID }` because `ofg` doesn't have a `FullName` property, the model I suggested has one.  You'd need to select an instance of that model, and wouldn't need to supply a `FullName` value because it's a calculated value on the model itself.

Comment: Oops, sorry David! I understand now, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding name for properties in anon object, for smaple:

```
public ActionResult GetContactList (int? id) {

    var contacts = from ofg in db.Contacts
                   where ((ofg.ContactId == id) && (ofg.Deleted == false))
                   order by ofg.FirstName
                   select new { FullName = (ofg.FirstName + ofg.Surname), 
                                ContactID = ofg.ContactID };

    return this.Direct(contacts.ToArray());

}
```